# Как нарисовать стрелку в android

Tags: java, android, canvas

как можно нарисовать стрелку в Android [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [How do I draw an arrowhead (in Android)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713757/how-do-i-draw-an-arrowhead-in-android) ???

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я смотрел этот ответ уже, но почему то у меня не рисуется стрелка, а треугольник получается )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно кому-то пригодится именно нарисованная стрелочка:

```
public class DrawArrow extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(new DrawView(this));
}

class DrawView extends View {
    Paint p;
    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        p = new Paint();
        p.setStrokeWidth(7);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawPath(makeArrow(200,100), p);
    }
}

private Path makeArrow(float length, float height) { //=height/2
    Path path = new Path();
    path.reset();
    path.moveTo(0.0f, height * 0.5f);
    path.lineTo(length, height * 0.5f);
    path.lineTo(length*0.97f, height * 0.35f);
    path.lineTo(length*1.2f, height*0.5f);
    path.lineTo(length*0.97f, height*0.65f);
    path.lineTo(length, height * 0.5f);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А 9-patch чем не понравился???

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]